# Ibus does not show option in input method except Chinese

Tags: 11.04, internationalization, ibus

I have just started using Ubuntu 11.04 (any Linux OS for that matter). I am trying to get Hindi phonetic typing option to work. so far I have not been able to figure it out.
Can you tell me step by step how to do it.

I have already checked Hindi in language support, I have also tried getting m17n using terminal commands as suggested in similar forums, but it does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

First of all install or check that you have installed `ibus-m17n`.

`sudo apt-get install ibus-m17n` or using software center/synaptic. Then choose `ibus` as input method

[image]

Launch `Keyboard Input Method` It will prompt for starting ibus if it isn't already started check `yes`:

[image]

This will give you a additional keyboard indicator in the panel. Then go to `Input Method` tab and choose `Hindi Phonetic` as your input method and add it.

[image]